# Как получить frequency текущей точки доступа WIFI?

Tags: java, android, wifi

Как получить frequency текущей точки доступа WIFI для API меньших чем 21?

Comment: буду рад ошибаться, но похоже, что никак. Обычно, ели я не знаю ответа, и погуглив 10 минут не нашел его, значит что никак...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я вижу, `ScanResult` класс доступен с API 1.  Поэтому можно попробовать что-то типа:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> list = wifi.getScanResults();

if (list != null) {
    ScanResult scanResult;

    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        scanResult = list.get(i);

        if (scanResult == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(scanResult.SSID)) {
            continue;
        }

        Log.d("wifi", scanResult.SSID + " => " + scanResult.frequency);
    }
}
```

Посмотрите [документацию к ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) - там еще много чего можно получить.

Comment: Засчитано, а почему цикл с конца )?

Comment: @Andreyua Да, в принципе, никакой разницы.  Я использовал кусок кода из другого места - там был цикл с конца - только и всего.

Comment: Может ошибаюсь, но в конце находяться точки с более плохим качеством..

Comment: Насколько я знаю, список создается по мере нахождения точек, так что в конце будут точки, найденные последними - вне зависимости от силы сигнала.  Но, в принципе, это ведь всего лишь демонстрация :)  Могу поменять цикл наоборот.

Comment: Да нет, не стоит )). Я всего лишь хотел разобраться...